# sorting a list of pair of integers in ascending order in java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I am using the javafx pair class and trying to sort them using the second value.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> dist = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
    dist.add(new Pair <Integer,Integer> (4,54));
    dist.add(new Pair <Integer,Integer> (6,94));
    dist.add(new Pair <Integer,Integer> (7,4));
    dist.add(new Pair <Integer,Integer> (11,9));

    Collections.sort(dist, new ListComparator<>());

    System.out.println(dist);

     }

 public class ListComparator implements Comparator {

 @Override
public int compare(Pair<Integer, Integer> o1, Pair<Integer, Integer> o2) {
        return o1.getValue() - o2.getValue();

    }
  }
```

i keep getting the following errors and warning.

> `/tmp/java_izg9ZN/Main.java:34`: **error**: cannot infer type arguments for
>   `ListComparator` `Collections.sort(dist, new ListComparator<>());`
>    reason: cannot use '`<>`' with **non-generic** class `ListComparator`
>
> `/tmp/java_izg9ZN/ListComparator.java:21`: **error**: `ListComparator` is **not**
>   **abstract** and does not override abstract method `compare(Object,Object)`
>   in `Comparator` `public class ListComparator implements Comparator {`
>
> `/tmp/java_izg9ZN/ListComparator.java:23`: **error**: method does **not**
>   **override** or implement a method from a supertype
>       `@Override`

i have no idea what i am doing wrong because i example i looked at to do this did exactly the same thing so i really dont know what i have done wrong. please help! thanks

Comment: `implements Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>>`

Comment: that gives me this error: cannot infer type arguments for ListComparator
Collections.sort(dist, new ListComparator<>());
                                         ^
  reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class ListComparator
1 error

Comment: `new ListComparator<>()` is not a thing because your class doesn't take a generic, so it is failing, you need `public class ListComparator<E>` to do that

Comment: In addition to the changes suggested by the answer, you should get rid of subtraction in the Comparator. It should return Integer.compare(o1.getValue(), o2.getValue()). You won't notice the difference for small values but your version is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has **two problems**. First you call:

```
Collections.sort(dist, new ListComparator<>());
```

So you tell Java to use a `ListComparator` which infers the type by itself (diamond operator `<>`).

However your `ListComparator` class is **not generic**. It does not expect any type arguments, like a `String` for example, you don't write `String<...>`.

You could fix this by making `ListComparator` generic, working on the elements of the `List` for example:

```
public class ListComparator<E> implements Comparator<E> {
    // Compare E elements ...
}
```

However it seems that you rather want a **non-generic** `ListComparator` which is fixed to comparing `Pair<Integer, Integer>` elements. In that case remove the diamond operator:

```
Collections.sort(dist, new ListComparator());
```

---

The second problem is that you use **raw-types** for the `Comparator` instead of telling him the type of the objects that will be compared.

Because of that the compiler expects at reading `@Override` that your `compareTo` methods matches the signature written in `Comparator`:

```
public int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2)
```

And not

```
public int compareTo(Pair<Integer, Integer> o1, Pair<Integer, Integer> o2)
```

You fix this by explicitly telling `Comparator` what to use instead of using **raw-types**:

```
public class ListComparator implements Comparator<Pair<Integer, Integer>> {
    // Compare Pair<Integer, Integer> elements ...
}
```

Comment: omg that worked! thank u sooo much! and thanks for the explanation as well  :)